# Icons vanished from gnome desktop

Tags: fedora, gnome

I was installing virtual box using the latest development release from the official website. After working with it for a while, I installed it using

```bash
$ ./VirtualBox-7.0.5-154910-Linux_amd64.run uninstall
```

Just after it was uninstalled, all the icons (not just desktop icons) vanished.
[image: no icons]
[image: no icons]

No icons present in settings options
[image: no icons for settings options]

On top of that many gnome apps like `tweaks`, `gnome-terminal` are not opening up. I suspect that there was some bug in the virtual-box run file, uninstalled all icons while installing the software. How do I fix this?

How do I reinstall desktop environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was something broken in the `gnome` installation, fixed it using the following:

1. Install some other desktop environment, log out and log in with that desktop environment, I used xfce.

```bash
$ dnf install @xfce-desktop-environment
```

2. Open terminal in `xfce`, re-install gnome

```bash
$ dnf remove @gnome-desktop
```

```bash
$ dnf install @gnome-desktop
```

Power off and start the system again

```bash
$ systemctl poweroff
```

Change to gnome desktop environment, everything works fine.